# How can I compute the shape and orientation of the crescent for a given time and geographic location using data from the JPL Horizons?

Tags: the-moon, positional-astronomy

I can compute the following data for the Moon for a given time and geographic location using the JPL Horizons system:

- Apparent RA & DEC
- Apparent azimuth & elevation (AZ-EL)
- Target range & range rate (relative to observer)
- Illuminated fraction
- Phase angle and bisector

Is it feasible to compute the shape and orientation of the crescent from this data and if yes
how is the computation procedure.
I would be grateful if any one can answer this question for me.

Comment: For the orientation, the largest factor is the "parallactic angle".  You can find many sources for info by searching for that term.

Comment: The best source for the computation of the physical appearance of the Moon is Astronomical Algorithms, by Jean Meeus [1998]. Do you have access to it (personal copy, library copy, etc.)?

Comment: There's also "24. Sun-Target-Observer angle", which includes stellar aberration on the down-leg from target to observer.

Comment: Thank's for the answers. I can get a copy of Astronomical Algorithms, by Jean Meeus from the Bavarian State Library in Munich.

Answer (score -1):

I've written a blog showing how you can do it with sample formula and python codings here:
[Formulas to determine, or create, the illuminated phase and orientation of the Moon (Moon tilt) at your location, as seen in your sky](http://bthoven.blogspot.com/2022/02/formulas-to-determine-or-create.html)

Comment: Link only answer is likely to be removed. Please add the relevant details in the answer so that user can see without having to go to the link.